# PHP: How can I separate this split this string correctly?

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a bunch of URL segments.

I know they will either come in the form of:

```
myString?var1=value
```

or

```
myString/name.php?var1=value
```

In either case I need to take the URL and get the `myString` bit out of it. So something that will:

1. Search for either the first `/` or `?`
2. Turn whatever came before it into a var and throw the rest of the string out.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What you have tried so far.  ?

Comment: See http://php.net/parse_str and http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do it

```
$parts = explode('?', $str);
$parts = explode('/', $parts[0]);
$yourFinalString = $parts[0];
```